# TableViewCell has grey background after movement out of visible tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The following test app displays a simple tableView. The property `selectionStyle` of the prototype cell is set to `default` (grey). Since there are more cells than can be displayed, the first cells are visible, the last cells not. The background color of each cell is set to white.

**First test:**
When one of the cells is selected, its background becomes grey.
In the delegate function, its `isSelected` property is then set to `false`, thus the cells background becomes white again. The cell is then moved to row 0, and the data source is updated accordingly.
This works as expected.

**Second test:**
The tableView is scrolled up so that the last cells become visible.
When a cell is now selected, it is moved again to row 0, which has been moved out of the visible area of the tableView. This works again. However:
If the tableView is then scrolled down so that row 0 becomes visible again, **the moved cell has now a grey background, as if it were selected**, but it is not. This does not work as expected:

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var tableData = ["00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", 
                     "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19"]
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell")!
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[row]
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
        selectedCell.isSelected = false

        let sourceRow = indexPath.row
        let destinationRow = 0

        let removedElement = tableData.remove(at: sourceRow)
        tableData.insert(removedElement, at: 0)

        let destinationIndexPath = IndexPath.init(row: destinationRow, section: 0)
        tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: destinationIndexPath)
    }
}
```

**My question:**
Is anything wrong with my code?
Or is this an iOS bug? If so, is there a workaround?

**Please note:**
It is of course possible to use `tableView.reloadData()` instead of `tableView.moveRow(at:, to:)`. Then, the moved cell has no grey background. But in this case, the movement is not animated, as I need it in my app under development.
If property `selectionStyle` of the prototype cell is set to `none`, the moved cell has neither a grey background, but then one has no visible feedback of the selection.

Comment: Set the `isSelected` property to `false` while dequeue-ing as a workaround?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I did so immediately after dequeueing, but the grey background remains. Actually, I checked before that the cell is not selected after dequeuing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of set the `isSelected` property, call the `deselectRow(at:animated:)` method of UITableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    ...
}
```

Comment: I was not aware that setting `isSelected = false` is not the same as `tableView.deselectRow(at: , animated:)`, but the 2nd one shows the expected result. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a bug report to Apple and received the following answer:

> You should generally always use the deselectRow(at:animated:) method
>   on UITableView to deselect a row. If you only change the selected
>   property on the UITableViewCell currently shown for that row directly,
>   the table view will not be made aware of this, and when a new cell is
>   reused for that same row during scrolling, the table view will reset
>   the selected state of the cell to match whether it thinks the row is
>   selected. The table view’s state is always the source of truth; the
>   cell state is simply the current visual representation for a
>   particular row.

Good to know!